# Getting out hue values of points in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, hue

I have an image and I want to be able to get the hue values out of specific points on the image.

I've been using impixel to get out the color values, but was wondering if theres a function like impixel to get the hue value of speicifc pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`rgb2hsv`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html) after `impixel`.

Example:

```
im = imread('peppers.png'); %// example image
im = im2double(im); %// convert to double values in [0, 1]
c = [12 146 410]; %// column coordinates of desired pixels
r = [104 156 129]; %// row coordinates of desired pixels
pixels = impixel(im,c,r); %// rgb values of pixels
hsv = rgb2hsv(pixels); %// convert to hsv
hue = hsv(:,1); %// hue is first column of hsv
```

Comment: Well, thats a lot simpler than I was trying to make it. thanks.

Comment: Hi can someone tell me why I get this error when I try to replicate this example?
'Valid colormaps cannot have values outside the range [0,1]'

Comment: @VeilEclipse That's because the `rgb2hsv` function in newer Matlab versions requires that its input be `double` values on the interval `[0, 1]`.  I've added a line `im = im2double(im);` to solve that. See edited answer; it should work now